# Difference between Properties and Methods

Tags: vba

Im a little confused on the difference between a property and a method. When I think of this, I use the cells default values for my logic and how they change

Default value of a cell is:

Color = blank

Width = 8.43

--If we Set(change) the color to red, then this is referencing a property

--If we auto fit the cells width to say 10(Change the cells width), then this is a method

Either way, the values are being "Changed" from the default settings to a new one. How is it then, that a property and method are not the same??

I understand this logic is wrong. I guess im just trying to think of a better to way to think about it..

Thanks,

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-objects-properties-methods-and-events

Comment: One clarification: you don't set `auto fit ` to a value, you invoke the `auto fit` method, which set the width to whatever it chooses based on its own internal rules.  You can however set the `Width` property to any (valid) value you choose

Comment: Ok this makes more sense. Essentially When the object wants to perform an action, it uses a method. However, When you want to change a characteristic, you change a property.